# hitTest is intercepting touches from child controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, uitouch

I have a main view controller. Its `view` handles `hitTest`.

So when a particular point is touched, I would create another controller and add this controller to the main view controller like so:

```
[self addChildViewController:childController];
[childController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:childController.view];
```

It works, but my biggest problem is the main view is still intercepting all touches in its `hitTest`.

Here is my `hitTest` implementation:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{                
    for(int x = 0; x < [views count]; x++)
    {    
        NSValue *encodedRect = [views objectAtIndex:x];
        CGRect rect;
        [encodedRect getValue:&rect];

        if(CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point))
        {
            foundTheTouchedPoint = YES;
            return;
        }
    }

    if(foundTheTouchedPoint)
    {
        //This is a method where [self addChildViewController..]; etc takes place
        [self.myController createChildController];

        return self.myController.controller.view;
        //myController is the controller of this view.
        //controller is a property of myController, whose view I would like to 
        //receive touch once the touch validates.
    }
    else
    {
        return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

I just would like to be able to use `hitTest` to test a touch, once the touch validates, I would add the child view controller and its view as subview and have it receives touches (not the main view). And it has been driving me nuts. Please let me know what I have done wrong here.

***Another thing is:*** I think my design is wrong here because this view should not / need not to grab a hold of its controller (`myController`). But I need to be able to return the view of the controller (`controller`) from `myController` in `hitTest`, that's why I do this.

Though my gut feeling tells me my design is wrong, I don't know how to design it better. But this would be the second step, now I would like to be able to have that controller (`controller`) to receive touches once it is added.

Current controller / view hierarchy:

> [main controller]
>
> ```
>     \
>
>  [view] (handles hitTest)
> ```
>
> touch validates:
>
> Main controller add another controller as childController, whose touch is being intercepted by `hitTest` in view of main controller.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the touch that creates the child view controller to *also* be handled by the child view controller? Or are you saying you just want subsequent touches to be passed to the child view controller? Also, what is `views` in your code?

Comment: @JesseRusak Yes, once the child view controller is added, I would like it to receive touches, but currently `hitTest` (in view of the main controller) is getting all touches even though the child view controller and its view are added as shown. `views` is an array and it is working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find it easier to make this work if you stop overriding `hitTest:withEvent:`. It will by default pass those touches to your child view controllers if you don't override it; mixing actual event handling in here is awkward. (It is that method's job to determine which subview should get the event, so you can't stop it from receiving events destined for subviews.)

Instead, you probably want to make a `UIControl` in your main view and use either its triggered actions or override its `beginTrackingTouches:withEvent:` method in order to create the child view controllers.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more, because I have never used `beginTrackingTouches:withEvent:`, how would I use that to pass touches to child controller and when the child view controller is no longer in view to have it relinquish touches and the main controller again takes control of touches?

Comment: I'm saying that the default implementation of `hitTest:withEvent:` will correctly pass touches to child view controllers while they are visible, and stop passing touches to them when they are removed. All you need to do is add them to the view with `addSubview:` as you already are. `beginTrackingTouches:withEvent:` will just give you a place to put your code to add the child vcs.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested? Are you sure there isn't another view on top of your child view controllers which is accepting the event?